# Search Filter in Xamarin Listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I'm trying to create a program in which I can enter the data and delete the data. I did all the other parts except the search part. I couldn't make a working search box. My codes are below **:**

**TalepInfoPage.xaml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SqLiteXamarinCrud"
             x:Class="SqLiteXamarinCrud.Views.TalepInfoPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>

        <local:TalepInfoViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

        <ToolbarItem Text="Ekle" Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"/>

    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>




    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" Placeholder="Arama" SearchButtonPressed="SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed"></SearchBar>
            <StackLayout>



                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList} "
                      HasUnevenRows="True"
                      SeparatorColor="Blue"
                      SeparatorVisibility="None"
                      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
                      RefreshControlColor="DarkRed"
                      
                          >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                    <MenuItem Text="Favori"></MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem Text="Sil"></MenuItem>
                                </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                
                                <Grid Padding="10">
                                    <Frame CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100"></Image>
                                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">

                                                <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding ProductName}" FontSize="Large"></Label>
                                                <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding Aciklama}" FontSize="Medium"></Label>

                                            </StackLayout>

                                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                                                <Image Source="edit.png"
                                                   WidthRequest="30"
                                                   HeightRequest="30">

                                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                                        Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ProductId}"
                                                        
                                                        />

                                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>

                                                </Image>
                                                <Image Source="trash.png"
                                                   WidthRequest="30"
                                                   HeightRequest="30">

                                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                   Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding ProductId}"/>

                                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>

                                                </Image>

                                            </StackLayout>

                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </Frame>
                                </Grid>

                            </ViewCell>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <ListView.Header>



                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Ürün Bilgisi" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black"></Label>

                        </StackLayout>

                    </ListView.Header>


                    <ListView.Footer>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                            <Button Text="Daha Fazla" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Black"></Button>

                        </StackLayout>

                    </ListView.Footer>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**TalepInfoPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace SqLiteXamarinCrud.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TalepInfoPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TalepInfoPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Navigation.PushAsync(new AddOrEditTalepPage());

        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TappedEventArgs tappedEventArgs = (TappedEventArgs)e;
            TalepInfo talepInfo = ((TalepInfoViewModel)BindingContext).ItemList.
                Where(prod=> prod.ProductId==(int)tappedEventArgs.Parameter).FirstOrDefault();

            Navigation.PushAsync(new AddOrEditTalepPage(talepInfo));
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TappedEventArgs tappedEventArgs = (TappedEventArgs)e;
            TalepInfo talepInfo = ((TalepInfoViewModel)BindingContext).ItemList.
                Where(prod => prod.ProductId == (int)tappedEventArgs.Parameter).FirstOrDefault();

            ((TalepInfoViewModel)BindingContext).ItemList.Remove(talepInfo);

        }


    }
    }
```

**TalepInfoViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SqLiteXamarinCrud
{
    public class TalepInfoViewModel
    {

         public ObservableCollection<TalepInfo> ItemList { get; set; }
        public TalepInfoViewModel()

        {
            ItemList= new ObservableCollection<TalepInfo> ();
            ItemList.Add(new TalepInfo() { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "Deneme1", Aciklama = "Denemeler1", ImageUrl = "pc.png" });
            ItemList.Add(new TalepInfo() { ProductId = 2, ProductName = "Deneme2", Aciklama = "Denemeler2", ImageUrl = "pc.png" });
            ItemList.Add(new TalepInfo() { ProductId = 3, ProductName = "Deneme3", Aciklama = "Denemeler3", ImageUrl = "pc.png" });
            ItemList.Add(new TalepInfo() { ProductId = 4, ProductName = "Deneme4", Aciklama = "Denemeler4", ImageUrl = "pc.png" });
            ItemList.Add(new TalepInfo() { ProductId = 5, ProductName = "Deneme5", Aciklama = "Denemeler5", ImageUrl = "pc.png" });


            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddOrEditTalepPage, TalepInfo>(this, "AddOrEditTalep",(page,talep)=> {
            if(talep.ProductId == 0) 
            {

                    talep.ProductId = ItemList.Count + 1;
                    ItemList.Add(talep);

            }
                else 
                {
                    TalepInfo talepInfoForEdit = ItemList.
                    Where(prod => prod.ProductId == talep.ProductId).FirstOrDefault();

                    int newIndex = ItemList.IndexOf(talepInfoForEdit);
                    ItemList.Remove(talepInfoForEdit);

                    ItemList.Add(talep);

                    int oldIndex = ItemList.IndexOf(talep);
                    ItemList.Move(oldIndex, newIndex);
                }

            });
        }


       
    }
}
```

**TalepInfo.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SqLiteXamarinCrud
{
    public class TalepInfo
    {

        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Aciklama { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        internal static object Where(Func<object, bool> p)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having?  Just saying "don't work" is not helpful.  Are you getting an error or exception?  Have you attempted to debug your code to narrow down the problem?

Comment: I haven't run any "search" code I've tried. For example, in one of them, I got the error that the "Where" code is not defined. I just started this job. Of course I can add the Seachbar code. But I haven't made any progress in calling data in the search box. I would be grateful if you could add a "search" code which works . Because I need this program to run. Note: I will not use this program for commercial purposes.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can! This can be achieved through performing a search with **[event handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar#perform-a-search-with-event-handlers)** or using a **[viewmodel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/searchbar#perform-a-search-using-a-viewmodel)**.Please see my code snippets for your reference!

**1.Event handlers:**

Code in Xaml:

```
  <StackLayout>
    <SearchBar x:Name="CountriesSearchBar"  
             TextChanged="Handle_SearchButtonPressed"/>
    <ListView x:Name="CountrySearchList" Footer=""/>
  </StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
    List<string> countries = new List<string>
    {
        "Dominican Republic" , "United States" , "Spain" , "Costa Rica"
    };

    void Handle_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var countriesSearched = countries.Where(c => c.Contains(CountriesSearchBar.Text));
        CountrySearchList.ItemsSource = countriesSearched;
    }
```

**2.Via ViewModel:**

SearchPage.xaml

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <appsearchbar:SearchPageViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar"
               HorizontalOptions="Fill"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               Placeholder="Search fruits..."
               SearchCommand="{Binding PerformSearch}" 
               SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference searchBar}}"/>
    <Label Text="Enter a search term and press enter or click the magnifying glass to perform a search."
           HorizontalOptions="Fill"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ListView x:Name="searchResults"
              HorizontalOptions="Fill"
              VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
              ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

SearchPageViewModel.cs

```
 public class SearchPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ICommand PerformSearch => new Command<string>((string query) =>
    {
        SearchResults = DataService.GetSearchResults(query);
    });

    List<string> searchResults = DataService.Fruits;
    public List<string> SearchResults
    {
        get
        {
            return searchResults;
        }
        set
        {
            searchResults = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please help confirm if the solution is helpful to your question?